# Integrate Slack with Opencart

Tags: opencart, slack

we want to implement a slack snippet in Opencart 2.x such that after a successful checkout, there will be an alert on our slack channel. Where can one place this snippet in Opencart?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should create an event (try attaching it to `pre.order.add`), but if you need it done quickly and dirtily, you'll find the code that adds a new order in `/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`.